# ImageViewer in React Native not showing

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I cannot get result with ImageViewer.

Here's my code:
    return (
        
    )
////This code is working fine.
////But

```
return (
  <View visible={true} transparent={true}>
    <ImageViewer imageUrls={sliderImages} />
  </View>
)
```

////////Not working/////////
I can see only blank background with above result.
What's wrong?

Comment: did you try to set your View's style to flex?

Comment: You are missing part of the code. You mention something is working and the other is not. Please post the rest.